# Rails, dynamic user defined field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My question is the following:

I have two models : Products & brands.
Currently in the product form, the user is able to pick up a brand (via a select list) for his product. But if the brand doesn't exist he can create a new one by clicking on a link redirecting to the brands/new form.

Is there any way to handle the missing brand creation directly in the product formular ?

I hope I'm clear enough.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the form itself, you could allow the user to either select the brand from a dropdown **or** type the name of a new brand in a text field. I would use radios to force the user to perform one of those two actions, not both. The `<option>` elements would have a value corresponding to the brand name rather than the brand ID.

Then, on the Rails side, you could use `find_or_create_by_name`, assuming your brand names are unique:

```
# assuming a params structure like params[:product][:brand_name]
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def brand_name=(name)
    self.brand = Brand.find_or_create_by_name(name)
  end
end
```

The controller would still simply do something like this:

```
@product = Product.new(params[:product])
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really interesting. And what if the brand model contains a required description field ?

Comment: That gets more complicated. You could use `find_or_create_by_name_and_description` and have some hidden field that contains the brand description (which is a hack), or you could offer a modal dialog that allows the user to create the brand directly from the product page and reloads the dropdown menu upon saving via Ajax. That's a much more complex UX problem. You could also relax the requirement on a brand description and just allow brands to exist temporarily without a description. The user would just need to create the description sometime later.

Comment: to add my two cents, you can just use `find_or_create_by_name(name: name, description: "some default description")`. It will perform a lookup by name only, and use the hash to create a record if none was found.

Comment: @m_x Excellent! I didn't know about that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use jQuery for something like this.  Have the user select something like "New Brand" from the select list and then display an input prompt.  Use AJAX to create the new brand and then recreate the brand list in the form with the new brand selected.